# Is POST-based XSSI possible?

Tags: web-application, http, javascript, appsec, xssi

With standard XSSI, an attacker can include a remote script which contains user-bound secrets across origins, and then read them out.

I have an endpoint which returns sensitive Javascript code, but the request to fetch it is POST-based (the endpoint doesn't accept GET requests).

Is this secure? I assume that it is, and that XSSI isn't possible. But maybe there is some 3xx redirect trick or something else which can be used to exploit this?

Comment: I don't see how the VERB would impact XSSI.... I mean, its just about tricking the client to run your script...  the URI is not requered to make that attack possible..

Comment: @LvB The important part of XSSI is including the script cross-origin. That usually/always happens via `<script src="https://vuln.com/vuln.js"></script>`, so it relies on the endpoint being served via GET (of course it could be included via CORS, but that wouldn't be an XSSI issue). I was just wondering if there's some weird browser behavior or trick to still get XSSI to work with POST.

Comment: But…. That would mean your service is serving the bad JavaScript…. Otherwise the attacker would just fuse a GET serving one…. If I understand you correctly.

Comment: the (potentially vulnerable) webpage is returning the javascript. So the attacker doesn't have a choice in method when communicating with that server. It has to be POST.

Comment: How does Your web page load the POST retrieved JavaScript?  And if that server is the one sending the malicious script tag. How is it executed?

Comment: @LvB It's an application I'm looking at right now. I haven't checked how they process the received JS, but my guess is that they retrieve and then execute it via JavaScript (they can do that, as they are on the same origin). But the important part is that I want to retrieve and execute it from a different origin, to achieve XSSI (so I can't do it the way they are doing it, because I can't read out the response to a cross-origin POST request). I know it's probably not possible to achieve XSSI here, but sometimes there are weird behaviors, so maybe someone knows something.